# How to copy all *.txt files from subfolder to batch file folder using this batch-file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, copy-paste

I have main folder that contains "batch.bat" file and 1 subfolder named "Carrol".
This "Carrol" subfolder contains many files with different types.
I need to copy all txt files from "Carrol" subfolder to main folder with this "batch.bat" using commands of this "batch.bat" file

How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you Rene, but it have to be a batch file command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `batch.bat`

```
for %%i in (Carrol\*txt) do move Carrol\%%i %~dp0
```

Comment: Thank you for advice. In my case the right command line inside batch.bat is: for %%i in (Carrol\*.txt) do copy Carrol\%%i %~dp0 Sorry, my reputation level is too low to up yours, so I can only mark your answer as the best answer. Thank you very much!